# Match a cycle of letters in a string in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

Let's say I have a string 'abc'. How do I match all 3 or more occurrences of 'abc' and its cycles ('bca', 'cab') in a large string.

Right now I am using individual entries as regex to match, but a) It is taking too long because the string is very large, and b) I'm getting the same regions in subsequent matches. For example, if my input is:

```
dabcabcabcabgyklagkbcabcabcahkgljla
 ^-------^         ^-------^
```

I want my output to be two matches:

```
1. abcabcabc    position 2
2. bcabcabca    position 20
```

Right now I'm getting 4 lines of output:

```
1. abcabcabc    position 2
2. bcabcabca    position 3
3. cabcabcab    position 4
4. bcabcabca    position 20
```

I hope I explained my problem. I got the desired output in another complicated way by doing a multi regex matching using all possible combinations in a single regex like this:

```
while($str =~ /(abc){3,}|(bca){3,}|cab{3,}/g {
    print "$1\tposition $-[0]\n";
}
```

But it was a serious performance hit, and given the size of my input, it is taking forever to run. Please help me with a more efficient algorithm. Really sorry if this was asked earlier, but I couldn't find any page that helped me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edited your question for the asterisks thing, feel free to adapt at will...

Comment: Is this genetic/DNA scanning work?  You might want to consider using [Boulder](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/Boulder-1.30/) for the kind of scanning you are describing (extracting small strings from a large corpus).

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering how to highlight that part

Comment: @heptadecagram, Yes it is, I did have a look at it. But I don't think it does what I exactly want. I did not present the full output I want, and for that it is important to do the pattern match on my own. Thanks nevertheless :)

Comment: Your third alternation, `cba` is wrongly-ordered, and your pattern has unnecessary captures. I suggest you try `/((?:abc){3,}|(?:bca){3,}|(?:cab){3,})/g`

Comment: What size is your input string?

Comment: @Borodin My mistake, but that's a typo here and not in the original. In my original script I'm using a variable for regex. The String is about 100MB, and I need to do 500 different regex matches, each 6 letters long. So including their cycles, it's 3000 matches. And I have 300 or so of such 100MB strings.

Comment: You could also try `/((abc|bca|cab)\2{2,})/g`, but I don't think it will help.

Comment: @Lee Duhem, I already removed the comment with that problem. The match I posted above your comment does not suffer from that problem. Please delete your comment to avoid confusion

Comment: @user2862238 Have you considered using multiple threads or processes?

Comment: @LeeDuhem doing this on a regular laptop (Core i5 2nd gen) so that's not really an option

Comment: @user2862238 Not always you can find a fast algorithm to solve your problem like magic, sometime you have to have more computing power to solve it.

Comment: @LeeDuhem I do know that I can't exponentially make an algorithm faster, but any save in run time will be helpful. And considering I don't have an access to a cluster, I don't think I have any other option. I already got the output I want, but because I have to run this again and again, I'm trying to optimize the algorithm.

Comment: @user2862238 Beside trying to find a faster algorithm, another option is using a lighter implementation. For example, implementing your algorithm in C may avoid some overhead, and get a faster program.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use just `/(abc){2,}/` preceded by nothing, `c`, or `bc` and followed by nothing, `a`, or `ab`, so

```
/ ( (?:b?c)? (?:abc){2,} (?:ab?)? ) /xg
```

The idea is to break down any sequence, like `bcabcabcabcabca` into a number of `abc`s, possibly preceded bt `c` or (here) `bc` and possibly followed by (here) `a` or `ab`, like this.

```
bc abcabcabcabc a
```

so that the regex engine doesn't have to check for three diffrent strings at every point.

Doing it that way may find sequences up to three characters shorter than you require, but it should be faster and you can add an additional filter on length. Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $seq = 'dabcabcabcabgyklagkbcabcabcahkgljla';

while ($seq =~ / ( (?:b?c)? (?:abc){2,} (?:ab?)? ) /xg) {
  next unless length $1 >= 9;
  my $subseq = $1;
  chop $subseq while length($subseq) % 3;
  print "$subseq\tposition $-[0]\n";
}
```

**output**

```
abcabcabc position 1
bcabcabca position 19
```

Comment: That was some regex! Mind explaining what exactly is it doing? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that will be faster. `my $subseq = $1;` alone will make it slower.

Comment: @ikegami: That will happen only when there is a good chance that the match is long enough anyway

Comment: That's kinda my point. You needlessly copy every single match, including the long ones. How is that faster than having the regex engine comparing if the next char is a `b` or `c`?

Comment: Whether that is slower depends on how many matches are in the string, and I'm assuming very few

Comment: @Borodin There are about 10,000 matches in every string. Also, I ran this program, it did run longer than a simple regex matching with all the three options. In addition, the regex is something that I have to keep changing, meaning I can't hardcode into the program. May be I can, but to be frank your regex went above my head :P

Comment: @user2862238: Can you put a sequence that I can test with online? On pastebin.com perhaps?

Comment: Uploading both the sequence and the script to pastebin. Will post the links shortly

Comment: The script - http://pastebin.com/XfTmqNSN. I pasted a modified script earlier which doesn't work because of a variable clash. This is the correct one. Sorry about that..

Answer (score 0):

I've used the data you posted and have found a variation of my original solution that runs about four to five times faster than your original. Unfortunately the sequence you posted is only 225KB and there is only a single occurrence of one of the SSRs in it, so I don't know how representative it is.

Essentially, instead looking for a sequence of four rotations of the pattern, it looks only for repetitions of the core SSR, with an optional prefix and suffix that lets the overall sequence start anywhere within the SSR, like this

```
/ (?:AAT|AT|T|) (?:AAAT){3,} (:?AAA|AA|A|) /x
```

All of this regex is built automatically.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', 'chr1.txt';
my $seq = <$fh>;
close $fh;

my @ssrs = qw( AAAT AAAC AACC AACG );

retrieve_ssr('Sample', $seq, \@ssrs);

sub retrieve_ssr {
  my ($name, $seq, $ssr_list) = @_;

  for my $ssr (@$ssr_list) {

    my $len = length $ssr;
    my $n = $len == 5 ? 3 : 12 / $len;
    $n = 1;

    my $prefix = join '', map { substr($ssr, -$_) . '|' }   1 .. $len-1;
    my $suffix = join '', map { substr($ssr, 0, $_) . '|' } reverse 1 .. $len-1;

    my $re = qr/ (?:$prefix) (?:$ssr){$n,} (?:$suffix) /x;

    while ($seq =~ /$re/g) {

      my $start  = $-[0] + 1;
      my $length = $+[0] - $-[0];

      my $excess = $length % $len;
      pos($seq) -= $excess;
      $length -= $excess;

      my $seq = substr $seq, $-[0], $length;
      print "$start\t$+[0]\t$length\t$seq\n";
    }
  }
}
```

**output**

```
23738 23752 12  TAAATAAATAAA
```

Comment: Yes, I had pasted only a part of the sequence because I didn't want to paste the entire 100MB. Your code looks good, I will try and let you know the results. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It's almost what I want, and it does run fast. It is still generating duplicates when I'm giving the entire list of SSRs, but that's an easy problem to sort because the index of the match is exactly the same. Thanks a lot for all the help

Comment: @user2862238: But there was nothing in your own code to prevent that?

Answer (score -1):

It strikes me that you don't need to have 3 separate regexes, you really just need one regex like this:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\tposition $-[0]\n" while /(b?c?(abc){1,}a?b?)/g' mydata.txt
```

The idea is that the core pattern abc is matched as needed, and then you just need to account for the potential prefix of "b?c?" and a potential suffix of "a?b?" (if the prefix or suffix were longer then it would be matched by the main regex in the center).

As given this expression will find matches of 3 chars or longer, but you can obviously up the minimum length by changing the value inside {1,}

This solution does risk a few false positives in the prefix and suffix however, as it would match "babc", so you could run a 2nd slow search on the results for complete accuracy.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I will try to implement this, and if it is saving enough time then writing a secondary script to further short-list the original results shouldn't be a program. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's pretty much what I was trying to do at the start. You can make sure the letters before and after appear in the right order by using `(?:b?c)?` and `(?:ab?)?` but I ended up with a list of alternations instead

Comment: @Borodin: I agree your answer is in essence the same as mine... I hadn't seen yours when I wrote/posted mine.  Your answer also has the advantage of no false positives, though perhaps with some cost in performance due to the or chains.